# Rethrow Exception in Android SQLite Database onCreate()

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, create-table

Hey this is my onCreate method for a SQLiteDatabase that is of course called when a new database is created.  I want to catch any problem and log and then rethrow it for handling up above.  However the compiler is not allowing me to rethrow the exception, complaining that it is not handled.  This is on the line that reads "throw e;".

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {//arg0?
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        Checklist.createTable(db);
        Item.createTable(db);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(KnowUrStuffApp.TAG,"KusDBHelper.onCreate: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());           
        db.endTransaction();
        throw e;//SYNTAX ERROR: Unhandled Exception Type Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Raghav it's just for debugging purposes right now. But in the future I want a user interface component to handle giving a user friendly message to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, that you're throwing a *checked* exception. This can only be done when this exception is

1. directly caught and handled by a `try/catch`-block
2. or the exception is thrown "upwards" by adding `throws SomeException` to your [method-signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

However, in your case, you're overriding the `onCreate()`-method, which (in the base-class) does not throw a checked exception. Therefore, you can't override the method and add `throws` to the signature, because that wouldn't be an override anymore.

What you can do is, throw a `RuntimeException` upwards, which doesn't need to be added to the method signature:

```
Log.e(KnowUrStuffApp.TAG,"KusDBHelper.onCreate: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());           
db.endTransaction();
throw new RuntimeException(e); // Add the checked exception as the cause!
```

For more information on Exceptions (throwing and catching), see my blog-post: [Catching practice](http://codeisland.org/2012/catching-practice/)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) throws Exception {//arg0?
```

**EDIT**: Thanks, throws*.

Comment: Yes it's throws.  That causes a syntax error "Exception Exception is not compatible with throws clause in onCreate"

Comment: This won't compile. Check my answer.

Comment: I like your Jekyll-Bootstrap blog.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
```

to

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) throws Exception{
```

Comment: public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) throws Exception {//arg0?

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Exception Exception is not compatible with throws clause in SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase) KusDBHelper.java /Know Ur Stuff/src/com/geeksonhugs/knowurstuff/data line 75 Java Problem

Comment: You will also have to delete the `@Override` line, I think

Comment: well it has to be overriden I beleive

Answer (score 1):

add `throws Exception` to  your method.

Comment: This fixes that syntax error but causes another one "Type Exception Exception is not compatible with throws clause"